# Redirect Chain URL

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, forwarding, no-www

how can I solve the following redirect chain problem ?

http://www.website.com/ > https://www.website.com/ > https://website.com/

I want the forwarding above to be like

http://www.website.com/ > https://website.com/

Please help.

Comment: welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: There is nothing related to redirect in htaccess file. How can I do the forwarding I mentioned above ?

Comment: you have tagged htaccess here and its possible to do it in htaccess, you don't want to do this in htaccess?

Comment: I already want to do it with htaccess, but unfortunately I do not know the code I will write, so I want help from you.

Comment: *`http://www.website.com/ > https://www.website.com/ > https://website.com/`* wont happen without a htaccess code. What is the current htaccess you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://website\.com [R=301,L]
```

Place this on top of .htaccess.